# Excel: Get location of first and last non-zero cell in row

Tags: vba, excel

The second row in the screen capture below (row 4 in my sheet) will sum up the values on each column and divide this sum by something. Those values can always change, and I'm trying to find a way to make a selection from the first non-zero value to the last non-zero value so I could use that range, to create a chart.

[image]
I am using elsewere `=LOOKUP(2;1/(4:4<>0);4:4)`, which will return the last non-zero value of the row number 4, but I cannot use MATCH I guess because I might find other values equal to the last non-zero value, "earlier" in the range, and will not return the reference of that specific last non-zero cell.

I have tried `=MATCH(0;4:4;1)` to try to find the first non-zero cell, but this will return the location of the last zero cell for some reason.

Any ideas? VBA is also an option.

Comment: I you have a spare row then you could add a formula with an IF statement that could put "First" and "Last" above or below your data then use a lookup on those. Something like if(AND(A2=0,B2<>0),"First",if(AND(C2=0,B2<>0),"Last",""))

Comment: This might be an option but:

1. I would prefer not to create a empty row
2. It is possible also to have some empty cells between the first and the end one than I could have other "First" and "Last" that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have been able to find:

First non-zero cell address: `{=ADDRESS(4;MATCH(TRUE;4:4<>0;0))}`

Last  non-zero cell address: `{=ADDRESS(4;MAX((4:4>0)*COLUMN(4:4)))}`

I have added the `{ }` to point out the fact that the formulas should be confirmed with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` because they are `Array formulas`.

Hope it will help others!