# VBA Update source data for chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I am using VBA to generate a chart.

With the following code I can select the data from column number `11` to the last column, which I have stored in `LastColumnNumber` variable:

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(Sheets(SheetName).Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(1, LastColumnNumber)), Sheets(SheetName).Range(Cells(4, 11), Cells(4, LastColumnNumber)))`

Because I have a lot of zero values before and after the data that I actually need displayed in the chart I am using the following methods to find out the addresses for the first and the last non-zero cells:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42413582/2012740

How can I update the fist piece of code to implement the solutions from the linked answer, and narrow the range for the chart accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have mananged with the following approach:

```
Dim StartPoint1, StartPoint2, EndPoint1, EndPoint2 As String

StartPoint1 = Application.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TRUE,4:4<>0,0))")
EndPoint1 = Application.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(1,MAX((4:4>0)*COLUMN(4:4)))")

StartPoint2 = Application.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(4,MATCH(TRUE,4:4<>0,0))")
EndPoint2 = Application.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(4,MAX((4:4>0)*COLUMN(4:4)))")
```

And The chart source has become:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(Sheets(SheetName).Range(StartPoint1 & ":" & EndPoint1), Sheets(SheetName).Range(StartPoint2 & ":" & EndPoint2))
```

Hope it helps someone! Cheers!